# How to fix React 15.5.3 PropTypes deprecated warning when using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to start `React` project.
At latest `React 15.5.3` package, it appears following warnings:

> Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated.
>   Use the prop-types package from npm instead.

I have already follow the [blog](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html):

`npm install prop-types` and `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

but it doesn't work.
I don't use any `PropTypes` or `props` in code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            videoVisible: true,
        };
    }

    ......
}
```

How to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 44):

Pulled from Reacts blog - npm install prop-types, then use new code. Also it said you can get this error message if a nested component is not using prop-types but the parent is - so you need to check other components.

```
// Before (15.4 and below)
import React from 'react';

class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.text}</div>;
  }
}

Component.propTypes = {
  text: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

// After (15.5)
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.text}</div>;
  }
}

Component.propTypes = {
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have already follow this blog and I don't use any props in code, no luck.

Comment: Can you put the code up on github? Also you may not use props, but other libraries still do, for example Redux.

Comment: Oh yes as you said, I use the aframe-react, which use props. I've fixed that.
Thanks!

Comment: It seems your bug is fixed, I just wanted to add I have similar problem, I use jest and enzyme, and when I run my test suite I get the same warning, I can however see that Enzyme still has old < 15.5. syntax for PropTypes hence the warning.

Comment: @Contra, if the answer didn't actually solve the stated problem, you shouldn't accept it as The answer, even if it was nice and well-meaning.

Comment: @frandroid You're right. I voted the useful comment.

Comment: I was also getting this error from an external dependency that was using the old version. Had to update the dep.

Answer (score 0):

React v15.5.x adds new warnings [check here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html)

Downgrading React v15.5.3 to 15.4.x works for me

```
npm install --save react@15.4.0 react-dom@15.4.0
```