# Microsoft Fabric UI & create-react-app -How to get rid of React 15.5.3 PropTypes deprecated warning

Tags: reactjs, ms-office

First of all, I've read the latest and greatest blog about how to fix this issue at
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html and I read this answer that almost answered my question: [How to fix React 15.5.3 PropTypes deprecated warning when using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302963/how-to-fix-react-15-5-3-proptypes-deprecated-warning-when-using-create-react-app)

I've installed `npm install prop-types` and imported it into my code--see below.

From what I understand from that last link, even though I'm not using any props, my other libraries may be--which I think Fabric UI does when I'm trying to create this button component.

Here's my code:

```
 import React from 'react';
 var PropTypes = require('prop-types')
 import { PrimaryButton, IButtonProps} from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';

 class GetAllEmployeesButton extends React.Component<IButtonProps, {}> {

    render() {
     return(
      <div>
        {/*this bring up an error :-( */}   
      <div>{this.props.text}</div>

     <h1> this is redering ok </h1>
     <PrimaryButton
       text='Click Me'
       onClick={ () => alert('Clicked') }
      />
     </div>
    )
   }
  }

 GetAllEmployeesButton.propTypes = {
 text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
 }

export default GetAllEmployeesButton;
```

Still can't figure how to fix this issue. I'm sure there is something basic I am misunderstanding. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if you do `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'`